# Android AGP 4.2.0 + Java 11 compilation fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

with the release of Android Studio 4.2 and AGP 4.2.0 we now have an ability to use Java 11 in android projects. I did update everything to point to Java 11, but compilation fails. If I put back `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`, it works.

All the compilation errors are in databinding(? or viewbinding) generated classes and complaining that android classes or packages could not be found. And I tried lot of things already, nothing works, JAVA_HOME points to java11, JDK in studio points to java11 and still:

`some_module:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED`

```
../DataBinderMapperImpl.java:3: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.SparseArray;
                   ^
../DataBinderMapperImpl.java:4: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.SparseIntArray;

.. error: package android.view does not exist
```

So, what I have

```
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
```

`./gradlew -version` returns:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC
Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64
```

`java -version` returns

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

`javac -version` returns

```
javac 11.0.2
```

Will really appreciate any help,
thanks!

Comment: "we now have an ability to use Java 11 in android projects" I don't think so - on what grounds are you basing this assumption?

Comment: @laalto https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features  However, OP is talking about using AGP 4.2.0, so maybe he should try upgrading to 7.0.

Comment: Android Studio 4.2 comes with bundled JDK 11 -  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.2-bundled-jdk-11. And AGP 4.2.0 should also support Java 11 as per their what's new page.

Comment: How I read that is that AGP 4.2 tools need JDK 11 and come bundled with it but Android code itself is Java 8. AGP 7.0 is a different story.

Comment: I think this will be possible only with AGP 7.0 and later. https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#android_gradle_plugin_70

Answer (score 1):

You should update to `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1` to use `Java 11`, also set your compile options to

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

if you are using Kotlin, also

```
kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString() }
```